# Show dynamic range of data based on user input

Tags: excel

In my current Excel sheet I have a drop down list. Based on the choice the user makes in the drop down list I want to display data a few cells below. The data is defined in another sheet (but in the same workbook). I have no link to access or whatsoever.

How can I do this in Excel, preferably without VBA?

//edit:

To clarify:
In one Sheet I have the accumulated data that is going to be displayed. This data is static and cannot change based on user input.
On another worksheet in the same workbook I have a dropdown menu, that is generated from the above data. Based on the selection a certain range of the above data is to be shown to the user.

**Example:**
The data sheet contains a list of all quests in an RPG each of this quests is tied to a campaign. The the drop down list is used to select the campaign. Then below the drop down list the names of the quests which are tied to the campaign are shown and the user can enter additional information (such as "Completed", "Failed", etc.), which are then in turn saved in yet another worksheet.

Comment: Business logic is very vague: how the Excel Worksheet suppose to know what data to display based on user selection? Please clarify. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the selection is in A1, the required results to be pulled from Sheet1 ColumnC and *few* here means `3`, please try:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!C:C,0)+3)
```

Comment: While that works for a single selection, I need to display a range. See my edited question for more details.

Comment: Sorry. But I'm mediocre in excel at best. I haven't used it for much more than simple calculations. This is my first attempt at something bigger.